# Securing azure media services downloadable content

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Services for hosting video content which can the user can then download to his device. The solution I have found is to create a SAS url which is valid for a short duration. But even with this approach, a third user, say a person trying to steal the content, can download the content if he has the url and make a request within ths SAS url validity time.

Is there any other way supported by Azure Media Services, using which, even after download, only that user can view the file for which it is meant ?

Answer (score 0):

> But even with this approach, a third user, say a person trying to
>   steal the content, can download the content if he has the url and make
>   a request within ths SAS url validity time.

Azure Storage SAS also supports IP address based ACLing which basically controls for which client IP addresses the SAS is valid.

So what you can do is include the client's IP address in the SAS and only those client with the IP address included in the SAS can download the video. Unless the other person has the same IP address, any attempt to download the video will result in failure.

You can read more about this [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#shared-access-signature-parameters) and [`here`](http://gauravmantri.com/2015/10/12/azure-storage-shared-access-signature-enhancements/)

Comment: `I cannot have more than 5 SAS urls per asset`: This is not correct. You can have as many SAS URLs as possible. This limitation of 5 is for the access policies on a container i.e. you can have a maximum of 5 access policies per container. Using each policy you can have as many SAS URLs as you want to.